# Change Background Image Multiple Times JS

Tags: javascript

Everytime I click on body the background-image should change and repeat when the images are over. I tried this but doesn't work:

HTML

```
<body id="change-image">
</body>
```

JS

```
var images = ['../img/1.jpg', '../img/2.jpg', '../img/3.jpg', '../img/4.jpg'],
    i = 0;

$("#change-image").click(function(){ 
   $("body").css("background-image", images[i]);
    i = (i==images.length-1) ? 0 : (i+1);
});
```

I think that code should work, but it doesn't. I tried with backgroudColor and it works perfectly, but with images is not happening. I would love if u help me please!

Comment: Just a note: if your `$("body")` is *already* the clicked  element `#change-image` than use `$(this)` (inside your function) instead.

Answer (score 0):

background-image needs url like this:

```
    $("#change-image").click(function(){ 
       $("body").css("background-image", "url("+ images[i]+")");
        i = (i==images.length-1) ? 0 : (i+1);
    });
```

Comment: I think you have a typo: `"url+("` should be `"url("`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url:('" + images[i] + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point you'll be increasing the counter out of the available number of background images so... (also by using properly `url()` like `background-image:"url(image.jpg)"`)
 do like:

```js
var images = [
  'http://placehold.it/500x320/07f',
  'http://placehold.it/500x320/f70',
  'http://placehold.it/500x320/7f0',
  'http://placehold.it/500x320/0f7'
],
    i = 0,
    n = images.length;

$("#change-image").click(function(){ 
   $("body").css({backgroundImage: "url("+ images[i++ % n] +")" });
});
```

```css
html, body{height:100%;}
body{
 background: red none 50% / cover; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change-image">CHANGE</button>
```

The `i++ % n` will increment and loop-back your counter